# Ensuring correct input is given for 24 hour time format

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm currently trying to make a program that asks the user to input time in a 24 hour format (hh:mm). i then put it into a string and .split(':') it to seperate the hours and minutes and then make it one big integer. such as: user inputs "18:40" i then interpret it as 1840 and find a value for it in an array (I'm working on a transportation timetable). what I'm having immense trouble with is making sure the user has a valid input and asking the user to try again if: 99:50 or 12:80 is input. but extremely confused because i also have to check with the array to throw back an error message if the user tries to arrive to early. sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: Take a look at [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) if you know the specific format (or [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to rely on a bit of guesswork

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, and you will get a better answer. As this stands, it looks like a "give me the code" request, and you'll get downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: not requesting for code. specifically need just a point in the right direction. like the title says I'm a newbie and just been trying to while loop it but not really seeing it as a viable option

Comment: So, include the code as I said - a `while` loop *is* the right way to do this in a console app!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it in c#:

```
bool validTime(string time) {
    return TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out TimeSpan t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and convert then separately to integers. Validate each if they are within a range. Don't concat the hours and minutes. If you want 1 integer number, you might want it as minutes.  `(hours * 60) + minutes`

---

You should use the `DateTime.TryParse()` for this. Because it's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the user input is in a valid range, as you asked, just split the string as you did. Parce the parts in an `int` and validate the parts.

```
    public bool CheckUserInput(string ui)
    {
        string[] parts = ui.Split(':');
        if (parts.Count()==2)
        {
            int hour = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            int mins = int.Parse(parts[1]);
            if (hour >= 0 && hour < 24 && mins >= 0 && mins < 60)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is it this what you need?

Answer (score -1):

Parse the string as `DateTime`, and then work with it. Also, it would be better to store the time in an appropriate format in the database, e.g. as [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx).

```
    string input = "18:40";
    DateTime time;

    var ok = DateTime.TryParse(input, out time);

    if (ok) {
        var timeString = string.Format("{0:00}{1:00}", time.Hour, time.Minute);
    }
    else {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid input, expected time in format HH:MM. Actual input was '{input}'.", nameof(input));
    }
```

**Edit**: use format string with leading zeros

Comment: @downvoter: please elaborate why you think this answer is incorrect!